# How to set adapter with fragment

Tags: android

I don't know how to add adapter to fragmentcategory please let me know if below is correct.my fragmentcategory is not showing any data.**adapterCategory = new GalleryAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<>());gridView.setAdapter(adapterCategory);** if there is any error please let me know.

FragmentCategory this

```
package com.kannada.newspaper.india.utils;
import static com.kannada.newspaper.india.Constant.getApiUrl;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import com.kannada.newspaper.india.AppConfig;
import com.kannada.newspaper.india.Constant;
import com.kannada.newspaper.india.R;
import com.kannada.newspaper.india.adapters.AdapterHomeCategory;
import com.kannada.newspaper.india.adapters.GalleryAdapter;
import com.kannada.newspaper.india.model.Category;
import com.kannada.newspaper.india.models.CallbackCategories;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
public class FragmentCategory extends Fragment {
    private Call<CallbackHome> callbackCall = null;
    SharedPref sharedPref;
    private View  root_view;
    private GalleryAdapter adapterCategory;
    private GridView gridView;
    private List<Category> mensWears;
    private GalleryAdapter adapter;

    public FragmentCategory() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestAction();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_phones,container,false);
        return root_view;

    }
    private void requestAction() {

        new Handler().postDelayed(this::requestHomeData, Constant.DELAY_TIME);
    }


    private void requestHomeData() {
        this.callbackCall = RestAdapter.createAPI(getApiUrl).getHome(AppConfig.REST_API_KEY);
        this.callbackCall.enqueue(new Callback<CallbackHome>() {
            public void onResponse(Call<CallbackHome> call, Response<CallbackHome> response) {
                CallbackHome responseHome = response.body();
                if (responseHome == null || !responseHome.status.equals("ok")) {

                    return;
                }
                displayData(responseHome);


            }

            public void onFailure(Call<CallbackHome> call, Throwable th) {
                Log.e("onFailure", th.getMessage());
                if (!call.isCanceled()) {

                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void displayData(CallbackHome responseHome) {
        displayCategory(responseHome.category);

    }


    private void displayCategory(List<Category> list) {
        GridView gridView = (GridView) root_view.findViewById(R.id.gridHolder);




        adapterCategory = new GalleryAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<>());
        gridView.setAdapter(adapterCategory);

        LinearLayout lyt_category = root_view.findViewById(R.id.lyt_category);
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            lyt_category.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            lyt_category.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:verticalSpacing="24dp">

    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>





    package com.kannada.newspaper.india.adapters;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.kannada.newspaper.india.R;
import com.kannada.newspaper.india.activities.MainActivitym;
import com.kannada.newspaper.india.model.Category;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<Category>  mensWears;
     public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List<Category> mensWears) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mensWears = mensWears;
    }
  @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mensWears.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }
 
  @Override
    public View getView(int i,View view,ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final Category mensWear = mensWears.get(i);
       if (view == null) {
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gallery_layout, null);
        }
        //For text
        TextView prdId = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        prdId.setText(prdId.toString());
    return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: `adapterCategory = new GalleryAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<>());` , you are always passing empty array list. Pass the data list you want to display, in your case `list` passed in function `displayCategory(List<Category> list)`

Comment: This example might help you- [gridview-in-android](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gridview-in-android-with-example/), Also it's better to use [recycler grid view](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recyclerview-using-gridlayoutmanager-in-android-with-example/)

Comment: `adapterCategory = new GalleryAdapter(getActivity(),lists);` . replace your array list with `lists` variable. you are already fetching the list in that.